# eclipse takes long time to initialize

Tags: eclipse, workspace

After selecting the workspace, eclipse takes about 10 minutes to initialize? What could be the problem?

Comment: How much memory does your computer have? I've had problems on systems with < 1 GB

Comment: I'm thinking this is a plugin issue, there is a way to start eclipse without any running add-ins, I just wan't find it, I'll post it in an answer when I can...

Answer (score 9):

besides eclipse.ini

try this

```
 Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown -> Deselect all plugins (if you have ADT, leave it)
```

also :

```
Preferences -> Maven -> Uncheck "Download repository index updates on startup"
```

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse shouldn't take this long to initialize unless you have a lot of plugins (especially buggy ones) installed. Do you get the slowdown after the workbench is already shown? That could indicate a plugin.

You may want to verify with your Eclipse installation how much max heap it is allocated. Eclipse traditionally ships with a very low default for modern machines. If you are on Windows, look at eclipse.ini in your Eclipse directory and change the -Xmx parameter to something meaningful (e.g., 2048M)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

- this [**eclipse.ini**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)
- running eclipse with the `-clean` option

Such a long startup time is usually the sign of some kind of timeout, because a resource (path, internet address?) does not respond.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by setting the socks proxy to the same settings as my http proxy in Window > Preferences > General > Network Settings. My eclipse start time went from 10 minutes to 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Check your workspace size. If its more than some 500 MB then its a problem. Drilldown to the file with maximum size and try to remove or move it out. I had similar problem and found out that there was one movie file of 1 GB and that was causing eclipse to slow down initialization.

Answer (score 0):

If your workspace has many open Working Sets, depending on your settings at start-up Eclipse might be building them all.

If this is the case, you could:

- deselect unused Working Sets:

  - in the Project Explorer, click on the drop-down triangle
  - in the drop-down, `Select Working Set`
  - in the panel that appears, deselect those you don't need
- if you don't want to deselect Working Sets, you could close projects you don't need all the time:

  - in the Project Explorer, right-click on a project and click on `Close Project`
  - *OR*, right-click on a project and click on `Close Unrelated Projects` (this reduces the start-up time **drastically**)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `eclipse.ini` doesn't contain the `--clean` parameter from a previous run.